# Getting the IP address in Vaadin behind an apache/tomcat setup (mod_jk) always gives the server's IP address

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, vaadin, vaadin8

Using the recommend Vaadin code to get an IP address in a setup with apache on the front and tomcat behind using mod_jk always results in getting the Server's IP address:

```
Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser().getAddress();
```

I caught [this snippet](http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43) which explains it's because the connection is coming from Apache, which makes sense, but that solution doesn't work either.

Therefore my question is how do I get the actual user's IP address in Vaadin 8 when the tomcat server is behind apache using mod_jk?

Comment: What is the "actual" address? The browser can only see the address it's connected to - seeing anything else presents an information leak and therefore a security risk. In any case, how would seeing (what I presume is) an RFC1918 address for your internal server be helpful??

Comment: I understand that but there should still be some way to confirm the IP address of the user, even if you're behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String header = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getHeader("x-forwarded-for");
if(header == null || "".equals(header)
    return "";
return InetAddress.getByName(header).getHostAddress();
```

It's best to do an empty String check just in case to avoid any `NullPointerException` issues.